# Dynamically constructing a filter from request.GET

Tags: python, django

I am building a form where users can select several options and a query built the filter the results. For example users can select one or more business vertical such as retail, restaurant on the initial form, on the second form they may choose implementation of the software which may be cloud, on premise etc... and more other fields to construct a query to filter the results. The values on each section(industry,deployment_model) of the form may or may not have values

I got the filter working partially with some errors. For example, if i submit the form with values on "industry" section which is the initial checkbox set on the form result returned is;

```
[<django.db.models.query_utils.Q object at 0x7f6b60b854d0>]
```

But if I submit with values only with last section of the form it works and returns results as expected.

```
def software_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = []
        if 'industry' in request.GET and 'industry' is not None:
            formattedq = request.GET
            #QueryDict instance is immutable so we need to make a copy
            formattedq = formattedq.copy()
            formattedq = formattedq.getlist('industry')
            softquery = Q(industries__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq])
            #debugformattedq = formattedq
            result.append(softquery)

        if 'deployment_model' in request.GET:
            formattedq = request.GET
            #QueryDict instance is immutable so we need to make a copy
            formattedq = formattedq.copy()
            formattedq = formattedq.getlist('deployment_model')
            depquery = Q(deploymentmodels__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq])
            #debugformattedq = formattedq
            result.append(depquery)

            result = Software.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, result))
    else:
        SoftwareSearchForm()
    return render_to_response('software_list.html',
        {
        #'software_list':results,
        'SoftwareSearchForm':SoftwareSearchForm,
        'formattedq':result,
        },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )

    return render_to_response('software_list.html', {'SoftwareSearchForm':SoftwareSearchForm})
```

---

```
<form action="" method="get" id="filterform"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='adsfasf' /></div>
<p><label for="id_industry_0">Industry:</label> <ul>
<li><label for="id_industry_0"><input type="checkbox" name="industry" value="8" id="id_industry_0" /> clothing</label></li>
<li><label for="id_industry_1"><input type="checkbox" name="industry" value="7" id="id_industry_1" /> food</label></li>
<li><label for="id_industry_2"><input type="checkbox" name="industry" value="5" id="id_industry_2" /> Apparel</label></li>
<li><label for="id_industry_3"><input type="checkbox" name="industry" value="9" id="id_industry_3" /> food truck</label></li>
<li><label for="id_industry_4"><input type="checkbox" name="industry" value="6" id="id_industry_4" /> Bar/Night Club</label></li>
</ul></p>
<p><label for="id_deployment_model_0">Deployment model:</label> <ul>
<li><label for="id_deployment_model_0"><input type="checkbox" name="deployment_model" value="4" id="id_deployment_model_0" /> On Premise</label></li>
<li><label for="id_deployment_model_1"><input type="checkbox" name="deployment_model" value="6" id="id_deployment_model_1" /> Software as a Service</label></li>
<li><label for="id_deployment_model_2"><input type="checkbox" name="deployment_model" value="8" id="id_deployment_model_2" /> server</label></li>
<li><label for="id_deployment_model_3"><input type="checkbox" name="deployment_model" value="5" id="id_deployment_model_3" /> Cloud</label></li>
<li><label for="id_deployment_model_4"><input type="checkbox" name="deployment_model" value="7" id="id_deployment_model_4" /> premise</label></li>
</ul></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm confused, what's your question? Do you mean you want to create a form-wizard? What would you like the end-result to look like?

Comment: It should basically construct a ANDed  Q query such as result = Q(deploymentmodels__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq] & Q(deploymentmodels__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq]))

Comment: Are you familiar with [using formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets)?

Comment: It looks like you're already using the forms API with your `SoftwareSearchForm`.  Why aren't you using it to validate the query params and extract your filters?  I tend to view directly accessing `request.GET` and `request.POST` a bit of an anti-pattern. Use the forms API on the submission side as well even when you're not using it to render the HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that result can hold 2 possible values.
A list of Q objects or a queryset.
In the `software_list` view you overwrite result with the queryset, but only, when the deployment_model parameter is set.
`result = Software.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, result))` is indented once to many. And as such is skipped when only supplying industry.

E.g.:

```
    if 'deployment_model' in request.GET:
        ...
        result.append(depquery)

        result = Software.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, result))
```

Should be:

```
    if 'deployment_model' in request.GET:
        ...
        result.append(depquery)

    result = Software.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, result))
```

Here's the whole method:

```
def software_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = []
        if 'industry' in request.GET and 'industry' is not None:
            formattedq = request.GET
            #QueryDict instance is immutable so we need to make a copy
            formattedq = formattedq.copy()
            formattedq = formattedq.getlist('industry')
            softquery = Q(industries__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq])
            #debugformattedq = formattedq
            result.append(softquery)

        if 'deployment_model' in request.GET:
            formattedq = request.GET
            #QueryDict instance is immutable so we need to make a copy
            formattedq = formattedq.copy()
            formattedq = formattedq.getlist('deployment_model')
            depquery = Q(deploymentmodels__id__in=[ind for ind in formattedq])
            #debugformattedq = formattedq
            result.append(depquery)

        result = Software.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, result))
    else:
        SoftwareSearchForm()
    return render_to_response('software_list.html',
        {
        #'software_list':results,
        'SoftwareSearchForm':SoftwareSearchForm,
        'formattedq':result,
        },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )

    return render_to_response('software_list.html', {'SoftwareSearchForm':SoftwareSearchForm})
```

Also there is a small flaw in the if statement: `if 'industry' in request.GET and 'industry' is not None:` Because the string 'industry' will never be None. You probably meant to use:

```
if 'industry' in request.GET and request.GET['industry'] is not None:
```

Or simplified (thanks Joe Holloway):

```
if request.GET.get('industry') is not None:
```

Comment: On your last sentence, `request.GET['industry']` will throw an exception if the key isn't present.  I think you mean `request.GET.get('industry')` which returns `None` by default if the key is not present.

Comment: left to right evaluation will prevent the right part of the AND to be performed if the left part fails. I.e. 'industry' in request.GET will ensure that 'industry' will be present if it is evaluated (it may be empty).

Comment: OK, that's true. I thought you were proposing to replace the whole line with that.  Regardless, doing it that way will require two hash lookups in the dictionary. If you condense it to `request.GET.get('industry')` you can eliminate a hash lookup and simplify the statement altogether.

Comment: @Joe Holloway On a normal dictionary the `.get` method seems to perform worse than the compounded statement (in determining `is not None`).

Comment: Looks like it's faster in the case where it can short-circuit (key doesn't exist), but slightly more expensive in the case where it can't (on average).  Hash lookups are relatively cheap so that doesn't surprise me, but I still prefer the condensed version for readability. I personally wouldn't sacrifice that in my apps for a couple ms in the case where the key isn't present.